# In Unity, how can I use an X, Y screen coordinate to find if there is a child of my Canvas object there?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hittest

Is there some Unity API that allows me to pass in an X,Y screen coordinate and figure out if there is a child of my Canvas object there? The HitTest from the camera seemed to ignore the children of the Canvas.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: (background information)
I've got a 2D game that resembles an endless chessboard, and I've implemented drag functionality and pinch-to-zoom functionality in a component attached to the camera. This works fine, but I've got a button bar on the side (made of panels and buttons, children of my Canvas) and if I drag from button A to button B it moves the map that's behind the buttons. In order to prevent this, I'd like this component to simply ignore any touch or click events that occur over GUI elements like Panels and Buttons, but I can't tell the difference.

Comment: Why do you need this? It would be better if you explain your current problem. Maybe there is a better way to solve this than what you're trying to do now

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to use [`EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject.html):

```
if( Input.GetButtonDown( "Fire1" ) )
{
   if( EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject() )
       return;
```

You can also derive your own control from `Button` and handle pointer clicks directly...

```
class MyButtonClass : Button
{
   public override void OnPointerDown( PointerEventData eventData )
   {
      base.OnPointerDown(eventData);
```

[`EventSystem.currentSelectedGameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem-currentSelectedGameObject.html) can also come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that ended up working for me was suggested by vakabaka on the Unity forums. It was to use the GraphicsRayCaster:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.GraphicRaycaster.Raycast.html

Their answer is here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/did-the-user-click-a-menu-object.578026/#post-3859102

the IsPointerOverGameObject may work as well, but I had trouble with it earlier and I'm not sure how well it would work for multi-touch scenarios.

Thanks everyone!